# How to set CPU affinity for a process from C or C++ in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, smp, affinity

Is there a programmatic method to set CPU affinity for a process in c/c++ for the Linux operating system?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use [`sched_setaffinity(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity).

For example, to run on CPUs 0 and 2 only:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>

cpu_set_t  mask;
CPU_ZERO(&mask);
CPU_SET(0, &mask);
CPU_SET(2, &mask);
int result = sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask);
```

(`0` for the first parameter means the current process, supply a PID if it's some other process you want to control).

See also [`sched_getcpu(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sched_getcpu).

Comment: This might compliment the technique: to query the CPU the thread is currently running on use this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491520/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-core-number-from-within-a-user-space-app-linux-c>

Comment: don't forget to define _GNU_SOURCE_ when compiling

Comment: Error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'result'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this still the recommended way to do it today?

Answer (score 11):

Use sched_setaffinity at the process level, or [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html) for individual threads.

Answer (score 7):

I have done many effort to realize what is happening so I add this answer for helping people like me(I use `gcc` compiler in linux mint)

```
#include <sched.h> 
cpu_set_t  mask;

inline void assignToThisCore(int core_id)
{
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(core_id, &mask);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask);
}
int main(){
    //cal this:
    assignToThisCore(2);//assign to core 0,1,2,...

    return 0;
}
```

But don't forget to add this options to the compiler command : `-D _GNU_SOURCE`
Because operating system might assign a process to the particular core, you can add this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=2,3"` to the grub file located in `/etc/default` and the run  `sudo update-grub` in terminal to reserve the cores you want

**UPDATE:**
If you want to assign more cores you can follow this piece of code:

```
inline void assignToThisCores(int core_id1, int core_id2)
{
    CPU_ZERO(&mask1);
    CPU_SET(core_id1, &mask1);
    CPU_SET(core_id2, &mask1);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask1), &mask1);
    //__asm__ __volatile__ ( "vzeroupper" : : : ); // It is hear because of that bug which dirtied the AVX registers, so, if you rely on AVX uncomment it.
}
```

Comment: How do you specify more cpu cores? instead of just one core?

Comment: @Thanks a lot, so basically a for loop would do the trick. really appreciate your help

Comment: Yeah, but note that process can not use other cores. It's useful for benchmarking.

Answer (score 6):

**`sched_setaffinity` + `sched_getaffinity` minimal C runnable example**

This example was extracted from my answer at: [How to use sched_getaffinity and sched_setaffinity in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490756/how-to-use-sched-getaffinity-and-sched-setaffinity-in-linux-from-c/50117787#50117787) I believe the questions are not duplicates since that one is a subset of this one, as it asks about `sched_getaffinity` only, and does not mention C++.

In this example, we get the affinity, modify it, and check if it has taken effect with [`sched_getcpu()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574301/895245).

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_affinity() {
    cpu_set_t mask;
    long nproc, i;

    if (sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask) == -1) {
        perror("sched_getaffinity");
        assert(false);
    }
    nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    printf("sched_getaffinity = ");
    for (i = 0; i < nproc; i++) {
        printf("%d ", CPU_ISSET(i, &mask));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    cpu_set_t mask;

    print_affinity();
    printf("sched_getcpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu());
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(0, &mask);
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask) == -1) {
        perror("sched_setaffinity");
        assert(false);
    }
    print_affinity();
    /* TODO is it guaranteed to have taken effect already? Always worked on my tests. */
    printf("sched_getcpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/4aff114c4c654014a97ef23b1513dda5409e79f3/userland/linux/sched_getaffinity.c).

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

Sample output:

```
sched_getaffinity = 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
sched_getcpu = 9
sched_getaffinity = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sched_getcpu = 0
```

Which means that:

- initially, all of my 16 cores were enabled, and the process was randomly running on core 9 (the 10th one)
- after we set the affinity to only the first core, the process was moved necessarily to core 0 (the first one)

It is also fun to run this program through `taskset`:

```
taskset -c 1,3 ./a.out
```

Which gives output of form:

```
sched_getaffinity = 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sched_getcpu = 2
sched_getaffinity = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sched_getcpu = 0
```

and so we see that it limited the affinity from the start.

This works because the affinity is inherited by child processes, which `taskset` is forking: [How to prevent inheriting CPU affinity by child forked process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336191/how-to-prevent-inheriting-cpu-affinity-by-child-forked-process)

**Python: `os.sched_getaffinity` and `os.sched_setaffinity`**

See: [How to find out the number of CPUs using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python/55423170#55423170)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

In short

```
unsigned long mask = 7; /* processors 0, 1, and 2 */
unsigned int len = sizeof(mask);
if (sched_setaffinity(0, len, &mask) < 0) {
    perror("sched_setaffinity");
}
```

Look in [CPU Affinity](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6799) for more details

Comment: you should use the correct type and macros for this (e.g. `cpu_set_t` and `CPU_SET`) - there's no guarantee that the bits in a `long` will be in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to make it through the shell without any modification in the programs with the [cgroups](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) and the *cpuset* sub-system. Cgroups (v1 at least) are typically mounted on */sys/fs/cgroup* under which the *cpuset* sub-system resides. For example:

```
$ ls -l /sys/fs/cgroup/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 380 nov.   22 20:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   0 nov.   22 20:00 ../
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root   0 nov.   22 20:00 blkio/
[...]
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  11 nov.   22 20:00 cpuacct -> cpu,cpuacct/
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root   0 nov.   22 20:00 cpuset/
dr-xr-xr-x  5 root root   0 nov.   22 20:00 devices/
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root root   0 nov.   22 20:00 freezer/
[...]
```

Under *cpuset*, the *cpuset.cpus* defines the range of CPUs on which the processes belonging to this cgroup are allowed to run. Here, at the top level, all the CPUs are configured for all the processes of the system. Here, the system has 8 CPUs:

```
$ cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
$ cat cpuset.cpus
0-7
```

The list of processes belonging to this cgroup is listed in the *cgroup.procs* file:

```
$ cat cgroup.procs
1
2
3
[...]
12364
12423
12424
12425
[...]
```

It is possible to create a child cgroup into which a subset of CPUs are allowed. For example, let's define a sub-cgroup with CPU cores 1 and 3:

```
$ pwd
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
$ sudo mkdir subset1
$ cd subset1
$ pwd
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/subset1
$ ls -l 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cgroup.clone_children
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cgroup.procs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.cpu_exclusive
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.cpus
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.effective_cpus
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.effective_mems
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.mem_exclusive
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.mem_hardwall
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.memory_migrate
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.memory_pressure
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.memory_spread_page
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.memory_spread_slab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.mems
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.sched_load_balance
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 cpuset.sched_relax_domain_level
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   22 23:28 tasks
$ cat cpuset.cpus

$ sudo sh -c "echo 1,3 > cpuset.cpus"
$ cat cpuset.cpus 
1,3
```

The *cpuset.mems* files must be filled before moving any process into this cgroup. Here we move the current shell into this new cgroup (we merely write the pid of the process to move into the *cgroup.procs* file):

```
$ cat cgroup.procs

$ echo $$
4753
$ sudo sh -c "echo 4753 > cgroup.procs"
sh: 1: echo: echo: I/O error
$ cat cpuset.mems

$ sudo sh -c "echo 0 > cpuset.mems"
$ cat cpuset.mems
0
$ sudo sh -c "echo 4753 > cgroup.procs"
$ cat cgroup.procs
4753
12569
```

The latter shows that the current shell (pid#4753) is now located in the newly created cgroup (the second pid 12569 is the *cat*'s command one as being the child of the current shell, it inherits its cgroups). With a formatted *ps* command, it is possible to verify on which CPU the processes are running (*PSR* column):

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,psr,command
    PID    PPID PSR COMMAND
   4753    2372   3 bash
  12672    4753   1 ps -o pid,ppid,psr,command
```

We can see that the current shell is running on CPU#3 and its child (*ps* command) which inherits the its cgroups is running on CPU#1.

As a conclusion, instead of using *sched_setaffinity()* or any *pthread* service, it is possible to create a *cpuset* hierarchy in the cgroups tree and move the processes into them by writing their pids in the corresponding *cgroup.procs* files.