# Get CPU number from running java program

Tags: java, process, pid, cpuset

I am running a java program and want to get the cpu that the process is currently running on. Is there any standard way in java to get this?

My backup plan is to run something like `ps -eF` to get the cpu for my current process but that seems ugly

Comment: why would you want this information?

Comment: Do you mean CPU usage or CPU ID?

Comment: I think you can use SIGAR library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data that you are looking for is not a static data but dynamic one and in my opinion should ideally be part of Java `java.lang.Thread` class where a method call similar to this `Thread.currentThread().getCPUNumber()` should give you that detail.

Java should shield OS specific system calls and provide that data at API level.

As far as I know, the answer is **NO** for your question - **Is there any standard way in java to get this?** because this data being dynamic and OS being thread scheduler, it couldn't be part of `System.getProperty(...)` OR `System.getenv(..)` OR `Runtime.getRuntime().` .

I guess, as suggested in these SO questions , you have to make OS specific system calls from within your Java Thread - [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491520/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-core-number-from-within-a-user-space-app-linux-c) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819655/what-core-is-a-given-thread-running-on) .

Hope it helps !!