# numactl --physcpubind processor migration

Tags: mpi, openmpi, numa, pinning

I'm trying to launch my mpi-application (Open MPI 1.4.5) with **numactl**. Since apparently the load balancing using **--cpu-nodebind** doesn't distribute my processes in a round-robbin manner among the available nodes I wanted to specifically restrict my processes to a closed set of cpus. In this way I plan to ensure a balanced load between the nodes in terms of the number of threads running on each node. **--physcpubind** seems to do the job according to the numactl manual.

The problem is - from what I could extract from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720332/numactl-physcpubind) post - that, using **--phycpubind**, processes are allowed to *migrate* inside this cpu-set. Another problem is, that some cpus from this set remain unused while others are being assigned two or more processes and thus running with only 50% or less CPU usage. Why is this happening and is there any workaround for this phenomenon?

Kind regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. If you have several processes, why not binding each of them to a given node? If you have one process, but several threads, you won't be able to specify something like a round robin policy using numactl. You would need to use the numa library and do that from code. (see http://linux.die.net/man/3/numa)

Comment: Open MPI supports processor and memory binding. See [this FAQ entry](http://www.open-mpi.de/faq/?category=tuning#using-paffinity-v1.4) for how to do it in your version of OMPI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this (It worked for me):

```
numactl --cpunodebind={cpu-core}  chrt -r 98 {your-app}
```

The *chrt* command lets you establish a scheduling policy, you can choose among the following:

```
Policy options:
 -b, --batch          set policy to SCHED_BATCH
 -d, --deadline       set policy to SCHED_DEADLINE
 -f, --fifo           set policy to SCHED_FIFO
 -i, --idle           set policy to SCHED_IDLE
 -o, --other          set policy to SCHED_OTHER
 -r, --rr             set policy to SCHED_RR (default)
```

EDIT: The number 98 is the priority, in my case I am running a time critical process.
Also, you may need to isolate the cpus you are using to prevent the scheduler from assigning/moving processes to/from them.