# How to set JAVA_OPTS in Intellij for a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I want to add JAVA_OPTS in Intellij for a Spring Boot project and I don't know where to add it.
I go to Edit configuration and then should I add it at the Environment variables like here:
[image]
But I don't think that it is ok how I set it because if I set it with this values `"JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1m -Xmx1m"`, the app started properly. And also how can I log the JAVA_OPTS? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add these to the VM options in your run configuration. Select `Modify options > Add VM Options` and put in `-Xms1m -Xmx1m`. Do not add `JAVA_OPTS=`, just the arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I already tried to add it there but it didn't work because I used JAVA_OPTS=. Anyway do you know how to set also the CPU? Should I add something here at the VM options?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking to do. There are a lot of variables to consider. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33723373/3059385

Comment: I want to set this microservice to use that memory and 2 CPUs. And I'm using Java 11. is this ok? -Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2

Comment: I'm not familiar with that flag, so I'd recommend reading through that question. It appears it doesn't actually limit the use to 2 CPUs, so you'd need some other way to limit available processors to the JVM. There are various solutions described in the answers to that question.