# running a process on a particular core of a processor

Tags: linux, operating-system, multiprocessing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CPU Affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280909/cpu-affinity)

On an x86 machine running Linux (fc12), can I make a process to run on a particular core of a multi processor system? I know there is a function `sched_setaffinity` which can help to choose the processor, but I want to execute the process on a particular core of a processor.

Comment: Curious, what is the use case for this?

Comment: @taz:I want to use al the cores for better performance

Comment: @anio I think sched_setaffinity is used to set affinity for a processor, i want to set the affinity for cores

Comment: "I want to use al the cores for better performance" -- you will very likely get the opposite. Do not tamper with processor affinities unless you know exactly what you're doing. It is almost always better not to touch them (the only allowable exception is running several heavyweight processes on a NUMA system). The OS will by itself make use of several cores, and not having a hard restriction on which cores may be used gives overall a better resource utilization (there are mechanisms to prevent threads from bouncing between CPUs senselessly, if this is what you are afraid of).

Comment: @ankur A core is considered a processor.

Comment: @anio I have 2 processors each one having 2 cores

Comment: "not having a hard restriction on which cores may be used gives overall a better resource utilization" This is true only if an underlying scheduling mechanism in use, such as by the processor, is more efficient than the scheme the user wants to implement. (Probably often a good assumption)

Comment: @ankur Physically we distinguish a processor and a core, yes. But as far as scheduling tasks there is no distinction because a thread can run on ANY core. The core is the lowest level of hardware that a thread can be mapped to. You cannot have a thread running on multiple cores at the same time.

Comment: @taz: Given the choice of leaving a processor core idle and not executing code (solely because of affinity mask) and running application code on that core, which is the better one? Sure, there is this thing about hot caches, but that's what the mechanism behind `sched_migration_cost` takes care of. Also note that your code may run on broken-by-design architectures where all your assumptions fail. The AMD Bulldozer architecture is an example of this. If you don't know _exactly_ what you do, your code will run ~20% slower. The OS (being "native" on the machine) hopefully knows.

Comment: @Damon I am not familiar with details of this subject. Are you saying that given the choice, it's better to run the instructions? And after looking it up, `sched_migration_cost` seems like exactly the kind of more efficient underlying mechanism I referred to. I am not advocating DIY for core scheduling. However, your point about architectures like Bulldozer remains valid. My understanding is that some platforms natively run well on Bulldozer and some are subject to inefficiencies due to the "broken-by-design" architecture (again, I don't know the details behind this).

Comment: @taz: I'm saying that executing code when a CPU is idle as opposed to not executing it is faster, and better (pretty obvious). The only issue being that caches won't be hot. However, this is a non-issue if it doesn't happen a billion times per second. Linux for example, by default, never migrates a thread any sooner than after 0.5 microseconds, which is roughly a million or so instructions. This makes the impact of cache effects neglegible, but at the same times allows a thread to run in a timely manner, when otherwise it would maybe have to wait for several milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, I used this code to make a thread run on a specific core.
Compile and link with -pthread.

```
#include "pthread.h"
#include "sched.h"

int affinity = 3; //core id
pthread_t mythread;
mythread = pthread_self();
cpu_set_t cpuset;
CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(affinity, &cpuset); //lets kernel know only core affinity may run this thread
if (pthread_setaffinity_np(mythread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset) <0){
    perror("sched_set_affinity");
}
```

Comment: pthread_setaffinity_np sets the cpu(and not core) affinity for the thread.A cpu may have multiple cores

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not distinguish CPU core from CPU. As far as Linux is concerned, core is full blown CPU. For example if you have 2 CPUs with 2 cores each, Linux will think that you have 4 CPUs.