# Is there an `x86` instruction to tell which core the instruction is being run on?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

When I `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, I see 8 cores, with ID's from `0` to `7`.

Is there an `x86` instruction that will report the core id of the core that the instruction itself is running on?

I looked at `cpuid` but that does not seem to return `coreid` under  any parameter setting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1*, section *8.4.5 Identifying Logical Processors in an MP System* lists, among others:

> This APIC ID is reported by CPUID.0BH:EDX[31:0]

Note that this doesn't directly equate to the linux kernel's numbering. In the kernel there is an `x86_cpu_to_apicid` table that you can read. Of course the kernel also knows what cpu the code is executing on, without having to consult the APIC:

```
 * smp_processor_id(): get the current CPU ID.
 *
 * if DEBUG_PREEMPT is enabled then we check whether it is
 * used in a preemption-safe way. (smp_processor_id() is safe
 * if it's used in a preemption-off critical section, or in
 * a thread that is bound to the current CPU.)
```

Comment: Follow-up, since you mentioned that "the kernel also knows". If I am running inside a kernel module, is there a direct way to get the Linux's Kernel's core number?

Comment: @merlin2011: Are you assuming the core won't change in-between the time you query the number and the time you make a decision based on it?

Comment: @merlin2011 come on, use the source!

Comment: @Mehrdad, No, I am trying to get a heuristic understanding of which core my kernel module is running its initialization on when I do `insmod mymodule.ko`.

Comment: @Jester, I am looking for source for  `2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64`. I have not yet found it.

Comment: I found it here: ftp://bo.mirror.garr.it/pub/1/slc/slc60alpha/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.32-71.el6.src.rpm

Answer (score 14):

Some newer x86/x86_64 CPUs have the "`RDTSCP`" variant of RDTSC instruction:

http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32-abc.html#R

```
RDTSC   EAX EDX IA32_TIM…               0F  31
        P1+         f2              Read Time-Stamp Counter
RDTSCP  EAX EDX ECX ...         0F  01  F9  7   
        C7+         f2              Read Time-Stamp Counter and Processor ID
```

C7+ means that "0x0F01F9" instruction was introduced in some "Core i7"...

> Opcodes
>
> Hex   Mnemonic    Encoding    Long Mode   Legacy Mode Description
>
> 0F 01 F9   RDTSCP  A  Valid   Valid
>
> Read 64-bit time-stamp counter and 32-bit IA32_TSC_AUX value into EDX:EAX and ECX.

OS should write core id into IA32_TSC_AUX (Linux [does](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.c?v=3.13#L330)), and this value is accessible with `RDTSCP`.

Linux [encodes](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.c?v=3.13#L341) numa id (<<12) and core id (8bit) into TSC_AUX:

```
341         if (cpu_has(&cpu_data(cpu), X86_FEATURE_RDTSCP))
342                 write_rdtscp_aux((node << 12) | cpu);
343 
344         /*
345          * Store cpu number in limit so that it can be loaded quickly
346          * in user space in vgetcpu. (12 bits for the CPU and 8 bits for the node)
347          */
```

In Linux there is also vsyscall [`getcpu`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html) ("__vdso_getcpu") to access cpu id  via `rdtscp` (if cpu has the instruction) or via GDT - GDT_ENTRY_PER_CPU: [__getcpu in include/asm/vsyscall.h from 3.13](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/vsyscall.h?v=3.13#L28). From the man page:

> getcpu() was added in kernel 2.6.19 for x86_64 and i386.
>
> Linux makes a best effort to make this call as fast possible.  The
>          intention of getcpu() is to allow programs to make optimizations with
>          per-CPU data or for NUMA optimization.

From some intel manuals: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf#page=15

> 3.2 Improvements Using RDTSCP Instruction
>
> The RDTSCP instruction is described in the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures 
>   Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2B ([3]) as an assembly instruction that, at 
>   the same time, reads the timestamp register and the **CPU identifier**. The value of 
>   the timestamp register is stored into the EDX and EAX registers; the value of the 
>   CPU id is stored into the **ECX** register (“On processors that support the Intel 64 
>   architecture, the high order 32 bits of each of RAX, RDX, and RCX are cleared”). 
>   What is interesting in this case is the “pseudo” serializing property of RDTSCP. The 
>   manual states:
>
> “The RDTSCP instruction waits until all previous instructions have been executed 
>   before reading the counter. However, subsequent instructions may begin execution 
>   before the read operation is performed.”
>
> This means that this instruction guarantees that everything that is above its call in 
>   the source code is executed before the instruction itself is called. It cannot, 
>   however, guarantee that - for optimization purposes - the CPU will not execute, 
>   before the RDTSCP call, instructions that, in the source code, are placed after the 
>   RDTSCP function call itself. If this happens, a contamination caused by instructions 
>   in the source code that come after the RDTSCP will occur in the code under 
>   measurement. .

Also, description is available here http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDTSCP.html which is clone of https://github.com/zneak/x86doc

UPDATE: There will be [separate instruction `RDPID`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/RDPID.html) just to read IA32_TSC_AUX register without timestamp counter (as [RDTSCP does](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/RDTSCP.html)

https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/RDPID.html

> Reads the value of the IA32_TSC_AUX MSR (address C0000103H) into the destination register. The value of CS.D and operand-size prefixes (66H and REX.W) do not affect the behavior of the RDPID instruction.
>
> ```
> F3 0F C7 /7 RDPID r32 M   N.E./V  RDPID   Read IA32_TSC_AUX into r32.
> F3 0F C7 /7 RDPID r64 M   V/N.E.  RDPID   Read IA32_TSC_AUX into r64.
> ```

It will be enabled since ["Ice Lake" microarchitecture (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Lake_(microarchitecture)), as declared in https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf 319433-030 OCTOBER 2017

Answer (score 5):

Except already described CPUID and RDTSCP instructions also there is new one RDPID instruction ([Intel SDM download page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#combined)) exactly for this purpose.

> Description
>
> Reads the value of the IA32_TSC_AUX MSR (address C0000103H) into the destination register. The value of CS.D
> and operand-size prefixes (66H and REX.W) do not affect the behavior of the RDPID instruction.

**Notes:**

RDPID reads processor core id as uint32_r or uint64_r, so read value will not in sequential range [0,MAX_CPU_COUNT]

RDPID is new instruction so it is not widely supported by hardware

Comment: What CPUs support it and what flag can be checked for its support?

Comment: @BeeOnRope, cpuid for rdpid is there: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf eax=07H - ecx bit 22 "Bit 22: RDPID. Supports Read Processor ID if 1."

Answer (score 2):

You see 8 “virtual CPUs”, rather than cores, so if you have, say a 4-core *Ivy Bridge* CPU with 2 hardware threads per core, you can see which pairs of vCPUs share a core via the entries in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-7]/topology/thread_siblings_list`.

Another answer makes the fine suggestion of using `cpuid`, but I don't think you can be certain that the `cpuid` instruction executes on the same vCPU as the instruction-of-interest, *unless* you pin the thread to a vCPU (in which case it's rather superfluous), since you cannot know that the kernel hasn't migrated your thread from one vCPU to another between the time that the instruction-of-interest was executed and the time the `cpuid` instruction was executed.

In short, the vast majority of the time, two “close” instructions will execute on the same vCPU, but it isn't guaranteed without pinning, and if you have pinned the thread, you already know what vCPU it's running on, so it's somewhat pointless.

Comment: It's not really useless, because often the CPU ID is used as a performance optimization rather than a functional behavior. For example, you might use the current CPU ID to index into a per-CPU counter to avoid contention, but in the very rare case that the CPU changes between when you execute `getcpu` and when you use the value, the code still does the right thing (with a possibly slight increase in contention).

Answer (score 1):

**`taskset` + `__rdtscp` runnable example**

And at last, for those that want to have some fun with x86 intrinsics + `taskset`:

rdtscp.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <x86intrin.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t pid;
    printf("0x%016" PRIX64 "\n", (uint64_t)__rdtscp(&pid));
    printf("0x%08" PRIX32 "\n", pid);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/ef4fa33ef7d8b67b36da4cbc9f155725fe191746/userland/arch/x86_64/intrinsics/rdtscp.c).

then compile and run while controlling which core it runs on [with `taskset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280909/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-for-a-process-from-c-or-c-in-linux/54478296#54478296):

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o rdtscp.out rdtscp.c
./taskset -c 0 ./rdtscp.out
./taskset -c 1 ./rdtscp.out
```

then for each run, the second line, which shows the CPU ID, matches the value set by taskset.

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 with an Intel Core i7-7820HQ.