# Linux kernel development, how to get physical core id?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am totally beginning in Linux kernel development. I am trying to learn about processes and scheduling (I know what I want to do is not "useful" it is just to learn).

I wrote a syscall which returns me the id of the thread/logical core on which my process is running.

But now, what I would like to do is: write a syscall which returns me the id of the physical core on which my process is running.

I tried to read the `task_struct`, but I did not find any clue.

I am a lost with all this code. I have no idea where I can start my research, and so on.

I am interested by your methodology. I'm on x86_64 and I'm using Linux 5.6.2.

Comment: An OS designer would likely not put much effort into providing such ephemeral data, stale by the time it is available.

Comment: I'm not sure to well-understand why those data would be ephemeral.
Also, for instance, in /proc/cpuinfo we can retrieve which logical cores are in which physical core. So, in my mind, those information are somewhere in Linux. Or maybe I am totally wrong.

Comment: ..because the thread may have moved to another core while the call is returning.

Comment: Oh! Of course! I was just focus about how logical cores are mapped to physical core.

Comment: You may look how `turbostat` utility finds that (it's x86 only solution, though).

Comment: @Reginas architecture and kernel version?

Comment: @Marco Bonelli, I'm on x86_64 and I'm using the linux 5.6.2

Comment: @0andriy thank you for this tool! I'll look at it, it could be interesting.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310678/634919 you can call `smp_processor_id()`.  Not sure if this still applies to current Linux versions.

Comment: @NateEldredge that returns the processor ID, OP wants the core ID associated with that. E.g. on an hyperthreaded scenario with N cores and 2N processors `smp_processor_id()` returns the logical core ID (`0..2N-1`), while OP wants the real core ID (`0..N-1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is basically the same thing that `/proc/cpuinfo` already does:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0  <== you have this
...
core id     : 0  <== you want to obtain this
...
```

We can therefore take a look at how `/proc/cpuinfo` does this, in [`arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.2/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c). By analyzing the code a little bit, we see that the CPU information is obtained calling [`cpu_data()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.2/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L178):

```c
static void *c_start(struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)
{
    *pos = cpumask_next(*pos - 1, cpu_online_mask);
    if ((*pos) < nr_cpu_ids)
        return &cpu_data(*pos); // <=== HERE
    return NULL;
}
```

The `cpu_data()` macro returns a [`struct cpuinfo_x86`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.2/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L80), which contains all the relevant information, and is then used [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.2/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c#L24) to print the core ID:

```
seq_printf(m, "core id\t\t: %d\n", c->cpu_core_id);
```

Therefore, in a kernel module, you can do the following:

```
#include <linux/smp.h>     // get_cpu(), put_cpu()
#include <asm/processor.h> // cpu_data(), struct cpuinfo_x86

// ...

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    unsigned cpu;
    struct cpuinfo_x86 *info;

    cpu = get_cpu();
    info = &cpu_data(cpu);
    pr_info("CPU: %u, core: %d\n", cpu, info->cpu_core_id);
    put_cpu(); // Don't forget this!

    return 0;
}
```

Dmesg output on my machine after inserting/removing the module three times:

```
[14038.937774] cpuinfo: CPU: 1, core: 1
[14041.084951] cpuinfo: CPU: 5, core: 1
[14087.329053] cpuinfo: CPU: 6, core: 2
```

Which is consistent with the content of my `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -e 'processor' -e 'core id'
processor   : 0
core id     : 0
processor   : 1
core id     : 1
processor   : 2
core id     : 2
processor   : 3
core id     : 3
processor   : 4
core id     : 0
processor   : 5
core id     : 1
processor   : 6
core id     : 2
processor   : 7
core id     : 3
```

---

**Note that** as [Martin James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james) rightfully pointed out, this information is not very useful since your process could be preempted and moved to a different core by the time your syscall finishes execution. If you want to avoid this you can use the [`sched_setaffinity()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) syscall in your userspace program to set the affinity to a single CPU.

Comment: Thank you a lot for all of these details! Today, I read about the `sched_setaffinity` and it would seems that this syscall is not 100% reliable. I mean, from what I understood, the scheduler could choose another cpu (which is not in the cpu affinity mask).. Maybe for some optimization reasons?

Comment: @Reginas you read wrong. Once you set the affinity the scheduler will respect it. You need to set it correctly though, of course. Also note that the `sched_setaffinity()` syscall is a privileged syscall (you may need to be root to use it).